# Spark data processing with grouping

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I need to group a set of csv lines by a certain column and do some processing on each group.

```
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile
                        ("somefile.csv");
                JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRDD = lines.mapToPair(new SomeParser());
                List<String> keys = pairRDD.keys().distinct().collect();
                for (String key : keys)
                {
                List<String> rows = pairRDD.lookup(key);

            noOfVisits = rows.size();
            country = COMMA.split(rows.get(0))[6];
            accessDuration = getAccessDuration(rows,timeFormat);
            Map<String,Integer> counts = getCounts(rows);
            whitepapers = counts.get("whitepapers");
            tutorials = counts.get("tutorials");
            workshops = counts.get("workshops");
            casestudies = counts.get("casestudies");
            productPages = counts.get("productpages");        
            }

    private static long dateParser(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mma");
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        return date.getTime();
    }
dateParser is called for each row. Then min and max for the group is calculated to get the access duration. Others are string matches.
```

pairRDD.lookup is extremely slow.. Is there a better way to do this with spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could simply use that column as key and do a `groupByKey`.  There's no mention on the operation on those rows. If it's a function that combines those rows somehow, you could even use `reduceByKey`.

Something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._  // implicit pair functions
val pairs = lines.map(parser _)
val grouped = pairs.groupByKey
// here grouped is of the form: (key, Iterator[String])
```

*** EDIT ***
After looking at the process, I think it would be more efficient to map each row into the data it contributes and then use `aggregateByKey` to reduce them all to a total.
`aggregateByKey` takes 2 functions and a zero:

```
def aggregateByKey[U: ClassTag](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, V) => U,
      combOp: (U, U) => U): RDD[(K, U)]
```

The first function is a partition aggregator and will efficiently run through the local partitions, creating local aggregated partials per partition.
The combineOperation will take those partial aggregations and combine them together to obtain a final result.

Something like this:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("somefile.csv")
// parse returns a key and a decomposed Record of values tracked:(key, Record("country", timestamp,"whitepaper",...)) 

val records = lines.map(parse(_))

val totals = records.aggregateByKey((0,Set[String].empty,Long.MaxValue, Long.MinValue, Map[String,Int].empty),
(record, (count, countrySet, minTime, maxTime, counterMap )) => (count+1,countrySet + record.country, math.min(minTime,record.timestamp), math.max(maxTime, record.timestamp), ...)
(cumm1, cumm2) => ???  // add each field of the cummulator
)
```

This is the most efficient method in Spark to do key-based aggregations.

Comment: I already tried that.. It is even slower..One operation is parsing the date column for each group to calculate a duration.

Comment: Could you add details to the question on the operation you're executing on the values for each key? `reduceByKey` is more efficient that `groupByKey` and could be the better choice.

Comment: @lochi  would you also have some lines of sample data?

Comment: Sorry.. Can't share the data.. but any csv will do.. The same dataset took about 10 seconds with a python script. With spark it might take 10 hours on my local computer. I want to know whether I am doing something wrong.. Thanks for trying..

Comment: @lochi updated the answer using the added information in the question

Comment: I need to perform different operations on different columns. They are not as simple as the ones on your example. If you can, please update the answer in java.. Can't follow scala..Only thing that actually worked out so far is collecting the whole thing into a List and process with a normal java program List<Tuple2<String,Iterable<String>>> grouped = pairRDD.groupByKey().collect();

Comment: @lochi re:different operations: in the example I'm showing you a counter, a set, a min, and a max operation. You can extend that as needed by your specific business logic. Re:Java: It would take 3x the amount of code to write this in Java with no added value. If you want to work with Spark I recommend you to learn some Scala. Just basics are needed to write a #Spark job.

Comment: @lochi if the data fits in a collection, in the memory of 1 machine, why are you doing this with Spark?

Comment: I wanted to see what the overhead is like if we run it on a smaller dataset.